# Text Editor keyboard overlaps with the recyclerview list

Tags: android, keyboard, android-recyclerview

The layout has a recyclerview and a text editor at the bottom of the view. When I click the editor, the keyboard popup and overlaps with the recycerview. I want the recyclerview to be resized when the keyboard is brought up. In my Manifest file I have :

```
   <activity android:name=".CommentActivity" 
                           android:label="yourtime"
                           android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                          </activity>
```

My layout looks like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="85"
        android:id="@+id/commenteditor"
        android:hint="Write a comment" />
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:background="#ffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How do I make the list scroll up or get resized when the keyboard comes up? I have tried encapsulate the recyclerview inside scrollview but that didn't work.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your

```
<activity android:name=".CommentActivity" 
                       android:label="yourtime"
                       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan">
                      </activity>
```

You cannot have more than one of

```
adjustResize|adjustPan
```

the results for this are undefined.

In your case, the one you want is

```
<activity android:name=".CommentActivity" 
                       android:label="yourtime"
                       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

You can read more about this here:

[activity-element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)
in the section that covers android:windowSoftInputMode

You should also adjust your layout so the recycler view is above the edit text container.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/rv"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"/>
```

Comment: Still have the same issue

Comment: did you make you're putting "adjustResize"? in your example you have "justResize"

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant to edit it to show what I now have in my manifest.

Comment: try adding the layout_above attribute to your recycler view

Comment: Cool it works but the problem is now the items are getting added from the bottom of the recyclerview. Thought it isn't a big deal but what's the reason for that?

Comment: I would think the reason for that lay somewhere inside your recycler view implementation

Comment: you were right. The recyclerview had a height of wrap content so it moved to the bottom. I changed it to match_parent

Comment: Thanks you so much. I've been scratching my head off all day to fix it.